# underscore to fill an array with large numbers

Tags: javascript, meteor, underscore.js

A Meteor server code using underscore to get the number sequence 2002,2003,2004,2005 when 2002 and 2005 are given
`_.range(2002,2005-2002)`
returns an empty array.
Also tried:
`_.range(2002,3)
Any ideas? thx

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#range . I think you using it wrong. You need to do like this _.range(2002, 2005); Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if 2002 and 2005 are given:

```js
var start = 2002;
var stop = 2005;

_.range(start, stop + 1) // [2002, 2003, 2004, 2005]

// Or just
_.range(2002, 2006)
```

[Read the friendly manual.](http://underscorejs.org/#range)

> Returns a list of integers from start (inclusive) to stop (exclusive)